# Como utilizar función en una columna de un select en Laravel

Tags: laravel, select

usando Laravel estoy mostrando una lista de clientes en un datatable, con eso no tengo problemas, pero lo que quiero hacer es agregar una columna a dicha lista, donde por cada fila se desea mostrar si el cliente está conectado o no a mi servidor mikrotik, para ello tengo una función que detecta eso. Algo pude hacer con Ajax, pero desde la vista. Lo que quiero es hacerlo en el controlador para que el código esté con el resto de las funciones de php y no tener la vista cargada de código JavaScript. Actualmente en el controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function getLista() {

//   $clientes = Cliente::select(['clienteId','clienteApyn','clienteDomi']);

//   return Datatables::of($clientes)->make(true);

return \DataTables::of(Cliente::query())->make(true);         
    }
```

Las líneas que están comentadas es porque antes utilizaba así y también funcionaba. 
El select sería algo como:

```
$clientes = Cliente::select([isConectado(), 'clienteId','clienteApyn','clienteDomi']);
```

donde isConectado es la función que devuelve 0 o 1, dependiendo si esta conectado. Pero hacer eso no es posible según vi.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien tu idea, pero te contestaré a lo que entendí.

Necesitas editar una columna de tu DataTables para que obtenga lo que retorna la función isConectado(), que por cierto no sé si es estática o no. Asumiré que no lo es. Por lo que te propongo esta solución:

En tu método getLista, cambiar tu consulta por esto:

```
$clientes = Cliente::select(['clienteId','clienteApyn','clienteDomi', DB::raw('1 as conectado')]);

return \DataTables::of($clientes)
                   ->editColumn('conectado', function ($cliente) {
                       $conectado = ($this->isConectado()) ? 'Conectado' : 'No conectado';
                       return $conectado;
                   })
                   ->make(true);
```

Y ya en tu vista, solo asocias la columna `conectado` en el data y el name de tu datatables.

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Answer (score 0):

María voy a probar esa sugerencia, aunque ya lo resolví pero no se si es correcto esa práctica que hice. 
Lo que hice es agregar en el modelo lo siguiente:

protected $appends = array('is_conectado');

Luego llamo a mi función isConectado() desde un accessor, lo cual me devuelve 0 o 1, así capto desde el datatable dicho valor en una columna que es dinámica por cierto, allí pongo una imagen según el estado de conexión.